# How to create any number of sublists using jQuery and Javascript array with objects?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, sublist

I have a simple `html` code of elements including `<div>, <ul>, <li>, <img>, <and> and  <spawn>` and by using css i created a menu with on hover show the sub lists. 
So because the `html` code became too large i decided to create dynamically the menu by using `jQuery` and a `javascript array with objects inside` but something went wrong with my code and works only when i have 1 sub-menu. But when i try to put a sub-menu to other sub-menu nothing appeared on the browser
Each `<li>` if have only 1 `<div>` inside no have sub-menu, If have and a second `<div>` this means that have sub-menu with the same loop
My current code of html looks like this:

```
<nav  class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <img src="files/img/nav/aaa.png"/>
                <span>Item 1</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <img src="files/img/nav/aaa.png"/>
                            <span>Sub-item 1</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <img src="files/img/nav/aaa.png"/>
                <span>Item 2</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried to generate the items i want with the following jQuery code and an array like this but i failed:

```
var menuData = [
    {
        "image": "files/img/nav/aaa.png",
        "text": "Item 1",
        "subMenu": [
            {
                "image": "files/img/nav/aaa.png",
                "text": "Sub-item 1",
                "subMenu": [
                    {
                        "image": "files/img/nav/aaa.png",
                        "text": "Sub-item 1.1",
                        "subMenu": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "image": "files/img/nav/aaa.png",
        "text": "Item 2",
        "subMenu": []
    }
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    function createSubMenu(arrayData){
        var elementsArray = [];
        var $ul = $('<ul/>');
        $.each(arrayData, function(index, value){
            var $li = $('<li/>');
            var $div = $('<div/>');
            var $img = $('<img/>', {'src': arrayData[index].image } );
            var $span = $('<span/>', {'text': arrayData[index].text});
            $div.append($img, $span);
            $li.append($div);
            if(arrayData[index].subMenu.length){
                $div2 = $('<div/>');
                $subUl = createSubMenu(arrayData[index].subMenu);
                $div2.append($subUl);
                $li.append($div2);
            }
            elementsArray.push($li);
        });
        $.each(elementsArray, function(index, value){
            $ul.append(value);

        });
        return $ul;
    }

    $ul = createSubMenu(menuData);
    $('.navigation').append($ul);
});
```

What sould i change on my code to works for any number of down level sub-lists???

Here is a working jsfiddle code with 1 sub-list: https://jsfiddle.net/za6bj2vs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have used global variables for the following two variables:

```
            $div2 = $('<div/>');
            $subUl = createSubMenu(arrayData[index].subMenu);
```

Thus they get overwritten when recursing, and backtracking. This gives undesired results; in fact it makes `$div2.append($subUl);` do something disastrous: as `$div2` has in the mean time changed by the recursive call, this actually attempts to append an element that is a parent of `$div2`, and so jQuery ... gives up.

Just use `var` and you're all good:

```
            var $div2 = $('<div/>');
            var $subUl = createSubMenu(arrayData[index].subMenu);
```